# Update query not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to update record with id using where clause but no success. I echo the last query and try that in phpmyadmin run sql query but not success. I have check the table name column names, all are fine.

```
    $updateData = array(

    'task_forward_to'=> 9,
    'task_forward_by'=>8
    );       

    $this->db->where('id', 32);
    $this->db->update('tasks', $updateData);

    echo $this->db->last_query();

    "update tasks set task_forward_to = 9, task_forward_by = 8 where id = 32
```

data types of both columns are int(11)

Comment: What means `try that in phpmyadmin run sql query but not success`?

Comment: I mean I have try that in phpmyadmin sql query area where you can type query manually and test

Comment: And what was the result of the test?

Comment: and what do you get if you try `select * from  tasks where id=32`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118827/discussion-between-mohsin-and-jens).